# summarise_all by either mean or max depending on the value with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a dataframe

```
d<- data.frame (type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (type=c("dna","dna"), value = c(20,30) )
d3 <- data.frame (type=c("protein","protein","protein"), value = c(-9.6,300, 1000) )
df <- rbind (d,d2,d3)

     type  value
1     rna    1.0
2     rna    2.0
3     rna    3.0
4     dna   20.0
5     dna   30.0
6 protein   -9.6
7 protein  300.0
8 protein 1000.0
```

What I would like to do is to either use mean or max conditionally.  Use max if there is even one value that that is < 0 else use mean.  For example in this example the final df should look like this.

```
 value    type
1   1000 protein
2    25     dna
3     2     rna
```

I tried to summarise as such but it errors out.

```
df %>%
group_by(type) %>%
summarise_all(
    funs(
 if (. < 0 ){max}
 else{mean}
) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap it with `any` as the `. < 0` is a logical `vector` of length greater than 1 and `if/else` works on a single TRUE/FALSE element.  So, wrap with `any` to return that single element

```
df %>% 
   group_by(type) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(if(any(. < 0)) max(.) else mean(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  type    value
#  <fct>   <dbl>
#1 rna         2
#2 dna        25
#3 protein  1000
```

If we need to get the mean of only positive numbers

```
df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean(.[.>= 0], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

NOTE: Here, we assume that in the original dataset, there are more numeric columns to get the `mean` of.  It is better to add `na.rm = TRUE` where ever the parameter is there.  If there are NA values in the dataset, it will remove it.

Comment: thanks! not sure if this should be a separate post but is it possible to instead of using max if < 0 to just ignore it and mean the rest? so for protein in this example the final value would be 650

Comment: @Ahdee Do you need `df %>% group_by(type) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(.[.>= 0], na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @Ahdee Did you meant `650` because I get `mean(c(1000, 300))#
[1] 650`

Comment: oh yes 650 sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think a regular `summarise` statement is more intuative in this situation.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(value = ifelse(any(value<0),max(value),mean(value)))

#  type      value
#  <fct>     <dbl>
#1 rna        2.00
#2 dna       25.0 
#3 protein 1000
```